# Custom google cast receiver stuck in "Load is in progress"

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

My custom v3 CAF receiver app is successfully playing the first few live & vod assets. After that, it gets into a state were media commands are being queued because "Load is in progress". It is still (successfully) fetching manifests, but MEDIA_STATUS remains "buffering". The log then shows:

> [  4.537s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load is in progress, media command is being queued.
>
> [  5.893s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Buffering state changed, isPlayerBuffering: true old time: 0 current time: 0
>
> [  5.897s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
>
> CastContext Core event: {"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","mediaStatus":{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"BUFFERING","currentTime":0,"supportedMediaCommands":12303,"volume":{"level":1,"muted":false},"currentItemId":1,"repeatMode":"REPEAT_OFF","liveSeekableRange":{"start":0,"end":20.000999927520752,"isMovingWindow":true,"isLiveDone":false}}}
>
> CastContext MEDIA_STATUS event: {"type":"MEDIA_STATUS","mediaStatus":{"mediaSessionId":1,"playbackRate":1,"playerState":"BUFFERING","currentTime":0,"supportedMediaCommands":12303,"volume":{"level":1,"muted":false},"currentItemId":1,"repeatMode":"REPEAT_OFF","liveSeekableRange":{"start":0,"end":20.000999927520752,"isMovingWindow":true,"isLiveDone":false}}}
>
> Fetch finished loading: GET "(manifest url)".

No errors are shown.

Even after closing and restarting the cast session, the issue remains. The cast device itself has to be rebooted to resolve it. It looks like data is kept between sessions.

It could be important to note that the cast receiver app is not published yet. It is hosted on a local network.

My questions are:

- What could be the cause of this stuck behavior?
- Is there any session data kept between session?
- How to fully reset the cast receiver app, without the necessity to restart the cast device.

The receiver app itself is very basic. Other than license wrapping it resembles the vanilla example app:

```
const { cast } = window;

const TAG = "CastContext";

class CastStore {
  static instance = null;

  error = observable.box();

  framerate = observable.box();

  static getInstance() {
    if (!CastStore.instance) {
      CastStore.instance = new CastStore();
    }
    return CastStore.instance;
  }

  get debugLog() {
    return this.framerate.get();
  }

  get errorLog() {
    return this.error.get();
  }

  init() {
    const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
    const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

    playerManager.addEventListener(
      cast.framework.events.category.CORE,
      event => {
        console.log(TAG, "Core event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
      }
    );
    playerManager.addEventListener(
      cast.framework.events.EventType.MEDIA_STATUS,
      event => {
        console.log(TAG, "MEDIA_STATUS event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
      }
    );
    playerManager.addEventListener(
      cast.framework.events.EventType.BITRATE_CHANGED,
      event => {
        console.log(TAG, "BITRATE_CHANGED event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        runInAction(() => {
          this.framerate.set(`bitrate: ${event.totalBitrate}`);
        });
      }
    );
    playerManager.addEventListener(
      cast.framework.events.EventType.ERROR,
      event => {
        console.log(TAG, "ERROR event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        runInAction(() => {
          this.error.set(`Error detailedErrorCode: ${event.detailedErrorCode}`);
        });
      }
    );

    // intercept the LOAD request to be able to read in a contentId and get data.
    this.loadHandler = new LoadHandler();
    playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
      cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD,
      loadRequestData => {
        this.framerate.set(null);
        this.error.set(null);

        console.log(TAG, "LOAD message: " + JSON.stringify(loadRequestData));
        if (!loadRequestData.media) {
          const error = new cast.framework.messages.ErrorData(
            cast.framework.messages.ErrorType.LOAD_CANCELLED
          );
          error.reason = cast.framework.messages.ErrorReason.INVALID_PARAM;
          return error;
        }

        if (!loadRequestData.media.entity) {
          // Copy the value from contentId for legacy reasons if needed
          loadRequestData.media.entity = loadRequestData.media.contentId;
        }

        // notify loadMedia
        this.loadHandler.onLoadMedia(loadRequestData, playerManager);
        return loadRequestData;
      }
    );

    const playbackConfig = new cast.framework.PlaybackConfig();

    // intercept license requests & responses
    playbackConfig.licenseRequestHandler = requestInfo => {
      const challenge = requestInfo.content;
      const { castToken } = this.loadHandler;
      const wrappedRequest = DrmLicenseHelper.wrapLicenseRequest(
        challenge,
        castToken
      );
      requestInfo.content = wrappedRequest;
      return requestInfo;
    };
    playbackConfig.licenseHandler = license => {
      const unwrappedLicense = DrmLicenseHelper.unwrapLicenseResponse(license);
      return unwrappedLicense;
    };

    // Duration of buffered media in seconds to start/resume playback after auto-paused due to buffering; default is 10.
    playbackConfig.autoResumeDuration = 4;

    // Minimum number of buffered segments to start/resume playback.
    playbackConfig.initialBandwidth = 1200000;

    context.start({
      touchScreenOptimizedApp: true,
      playbackConfig: playbackConfig,
      supportedCommands: cast.framework.messages.Command.ALL_BASIC_MEDIA
    });
  }
}
```

The LoadHandler optionally adds a proxy (I'm using a cors-anywhere proxy to remove the origin header), and stores the castToken for licenseRequests:

```
class LoadHandler {
  CORS_USE_PROXY = true;
  CORS_PROXY = "http://192.168.0.127:8003";

  castToken = null;

  onLoadMedia(loadRequestData, playerManager) {
    if (!loadRequestData) {
      return;
    }
    const { media } = loadRequestData;

    // disable cors for local testing
    if (this.CORS_USE_PROXY) {
      media.contentId = `${this.CORS_PROXY}/${media.contentId}`;
    }

    const { customData } = media;
    if (customData) {
      const { licenseUrl, castToken } = customData;

      // install cast token
      this.castToken = castToken;

      // handle license URL
      if (licenseUrl) {
        const playbackConfig = playerManager.getPlaybackConfig();
        playbackConfig.licenseUrl = licenseUrl;
        const { contentType } = loadRequestData.media;

        // Dash: "application/dash+xml"
        playbackConfig.protectionSystem = cast.framework.ContentProtection.WIDEVINE;

        // disable cors for local testing
        if (this.CORS_USE_PROXY) {
          playbackConfig.licenseUrl = `${this.CORS_PROXY}/${licenseUrl}`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The DrmHelper wraps the license request to add the castToken and base64-encodes the whole. The license response is base64-decoded and unwrapped lateron:

```
export default class DrmLicenseHelper {
  static wrapLicenseRequest(challenge, castToken) {
    const wrapped = {};
    wrapped.AuthToken = castToken;
    wrapped.Payload = fromByteArray(new Uint8Array(challenge));
    const wrappedJson = JSON.stringify(wrapped);
    const wrappedLicenseRequest = fromByteArray(
      new TextEncoder().encode(wrappedJson)
    );
    return wrappedLicenseRequest;
  }

  static unwrapLicenseResponse(license) {
    try {
      const responseString = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, license);
      const responseJson = JSON.parse(responseString);
      const rawLicenseBase64 = responseJson.license;
      const decodedLicense = toByteArray(rawLicenseBase64);
      return decodedLicense;
    } catch (e) {
      return license;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I have similar problem but no fix jet. Can you answers this questions: what device you are using? What version google cast? What media format? Are you defining ad breaks?

Comment: I'm mainly casting to Android TV boxes with built-in chromecast. The issue doesn't seem to be device-specific. Chromecast version is currently 1.36.168363. Streaming protocol is DASH (and widevine DRM). No ad breaks.

Comment: Today we have same luck with deleting cookies to unblock device. Tomorrow we will check this thoroughly and sugestion about LOAD handlers.

Comment: Thanks. So the session is kept and restored from a cookie?

Comment: What is the `LoadHandler`?

Comment: I added the implementation for both the LoadHandler and DrmHelper

Comment: @tvanlaerhoven - thanks!

Comment: Are you casting to an integrated or external chromeast? Did you enable gzip compression on respones?

Comment: It's an AndroidTv with integrated chromecast device yes. Gzip compression is enabled.

Comment: Ah, I guess the problem is the integrated chromecast. I'm also trying improve our CAF receiver on integrated devices, but I guess the battle is lost on those devices - the documentation is so bad! One of my colleagues force updated the chromecast firmware on the android tv and suddenly everything was much better. :shrugs:

Answer (score 1):

The handler for `cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD` should always return:

- the (possibly modified) `loadRequestData`, or
- a promise for the (possibly modified) `loadRequestData`
- `null` to discard the load request (I'm not 100% sure this works for load requests)

If you do not do this, the load request stays in the queue and any new request is queued after the initial one.

In your handler, you return an error if `!loadRequestData.media`, which will get you into that state. Another possibility is an exception in the load request handler, which will also get you in that state.

Comment: Thanks. Apart from this, is there a way to start the cast session with a clean state? So why is this state kept after ending the 'stuck' session?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to restart the cast session from the receiver to get into a clean state. CAF is from my experience not very flexible in the way intercepted requests can be handled. Handling the LOAD request in particular can be painful, especially if you need to do it asynchronously, and need to support handling a new LOAD request when the previous one did not finish yet. That might be another scenario that triggers the stuck in "Load in progress" ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess we have a different approach and send everything possible through `sendMessage`, when we loading stuff we create a `new cast.framework.messages.LoadRequestData()` which we load with `playerManager.load(loadRequest)`.

But I guess that you might be testing this on an integrated Chromecast, we see this problems as well!?

I suggest that you do one or more

- Enable gzip compression on all responses!!!
- Stop playback `playerManager.stop()` (maybe in the interseptor?)
- Change how the `licenseUrl` is set

How we set `licenseUrl`

```
playerManager.setMediaPlaybackInfoHandler((loadRequestData, playbackConfig) => {
    playbackConfig.licenseUrl = loadRequestData.customData.licenseUrl;
    return playbackConfig;
  }
);
```